# Как сверстать такое на CSS?

Tags: html, css

У этого "div"-а внизу маленькая стрелка если заметили, как сделать это?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дополнительным дивом (или ::after) снизу и его верхней границей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью псевдоэлемента сделать:

```css
.tooltip {
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -15px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Lesson Name</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Треугольники обычно делаются через трюк с `border`:

```css
.triangle {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
}

.triangle.to-bottom {border-top-color: red;}
.triangle.to-left {border-right-color: blue;}
.triangle.to-right {border-left-color: orange;}
.triangle.to-top {border-bottom-color: green;}
```

```html
<div class="triangle to-bottom"></div>
<div class="triangle to-left"></div>
<div class="triangle to-right"></div>
<div class="triangle to-top"></div>
```